# when checkbox is clicked I want Bvalidator to validate limited fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a form and it contains some validation using bValidator.   The issue I am facing is. When I check a checkbox  I want the bValidator to  validate limited fields only.  And when the checkbox is not clicked , I want the bvalidator to validate all the fields.   But the validation is already kept in the form element when created

how do I sort this issue out ?

Thanks
Abhinab

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be that you make those fields disabled when the checkbox is checked.
Or you can remove data-bvalidator attributes from fields when checkbox is checked.